# Angular NgRx - How Do I Send Multiple Sequential Http Requests and Return a Single Action If All Successful

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-effects

My Angular (v12) application implements NgRx and I have an Effect which iterates over a collection of objects (of unknown quantity) and creates an array of http requests. A simplification is as follows:

```
const requests: Observable<any>[] = [];
selectedStations.forEach(station => {
    const request = this.deviceApiService.deleteAllDevicesForStation(station.id);
    requests.push(request);
});
```

I currently use a forkJoin operator to send all the requests in parallel to the server and if successfull return an Action as follows:

```
return forkJoin(requests).pipe(
    map((responses) => {
        return fromDeveloperActions.UpdateActions.replaceAllSqlDevicesSuccess();
    }),

    catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => of(
        fromDeveloperActions.NumasImportActions.replaceAllSqlDevicesFail(
            { error: new Error(`Warning - Failed to delete all devices for selected Stations. HttpErrorResponse: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`) }
        )
    ))

);
```

However, I now need to send the requests sequentially and if all the requests are processed successfully return the same Action. The requests don't require any data from the previous response but if any individual request fails the complete operation is to fail. The requests must be sent in the order of the elements in the requests array.

So far I have tried many combinations of trying to use concatAll and concatMap such as the following:

```
        return from(requests).pipe(
          concatMap((request) =>
            request.pipe(
              map((response) => console.log(`Request successful. Response: `, response),

                catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => of(
                  fromDeveloperActions.NumasImportActions.replaceAllSqlDevicesFail(
                    { error: new Error(`Warning - Failed to update all devices for selected Stations. HttpErrorResponse: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`) }
                  )
                ))

              )
            )
          )
        );
```

I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions or guidance very welcome please?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
return concat(...requests)
  .pipe(
    // happy path
    tap((response) => console.log(`Request successful. Response: `, response)),
    ignoreElements(), // not interested in each response, so ignore them.
    endWith(successAction), // when all successful, end stream with success action
    
    // if error path
    catchError((err) => of(failedAction))
   )
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the prompt suggestion. I will try it out and get back to you.